# How can I configure permanent arp entries on Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Tags: redhat, rhel5, arp

I'm configuring a Red Hat Linux server which will be sending UDP packets out but never receiving ARP responses. So a static ARP entry is required.

The obvious way to do this is.

```
arp -s 10.0.0.1 distant_server
```

However that won't survive a network restart or a reboot. I could put it in the rc.local but that doesn't survive an ifdown && ifup.

The way I've found which seems to work is:

Add an entry to /etc/ethers along the lines of:

```
10.0.0.1 distant_server
```

And create a /sbin/ifup-local:

```
#!/bin/sh
arp -f
```

This feels really hacky, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper way to both store a permanent `arp` entry, and to run a command on interface start.

A less hacky way would be to have ARP working properly on the network...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [nethook](https://github.com/sciurus/nethook), a daemon that runs scripts when network interfaces change state.